# how add icon for customized login form in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

for project we used `wp_login_form` function for design a customized login form

we need to add an icon as a label , i tried :

```
$args = [ 'label_username' => '<img src="some url" >' ];
$form = wp_login_form( $args );
```

problem i faced is it show output `<img src="some url">` as string in label tag , but i expected it show the image .

could someone give me a clue

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5vrN.jpg)

look at picture for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter: `login_form_top`.  This will allow you to add custom html to the form above the fields...

Here is one way you could use this filter:

```php
add_filter("login_form_top", function($form) {
    return "<img src='http://via.placeholder.com/100x100' />" . $form;
});
```

Will look something like this (I have no styles added here):

[image]